# Modyfing the Legend in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, reshape2

I've got a problem interacting with the labels in ggplot2.

I have two data sets (Temperature vs. Time) from two experiments but recorded at different timesteps. I've managed to merge the data frames and put them in a long fashion to plot them in the same graph, using the `melt` function from the reshape2 library. 
So, the initial data frames look something like this:

```
> d1
    step   Temp
1  512.5 301.16
2  525.0 299.89
3  537.5 299.39
4  550.0 300.58
5  562.5 300.20
6  575.0 300.17
7  587.5 300.62
8  600.0 300.51
9  612.5 300.96
10 625.0 300.21
> d2
   step   Temp
1   520 299.19
2   540 300.39
3   560 299.67
4   580 299.43
5   600 299.78
6   620 300.74
7   640 301.03
8   660 300.39
9   680 300.54
10  700 300.25
```

I combine it like this:

```
> mrgd <- merge(d1, d2, by = "step", all = T)
step Temp.x Temp.y
1  512.5 301.16     NA
2  520.0     NA 299.19
...
```

And put it into long format for ggplot2 with this:

```
> melt1 <- melt(mrgd3, id = "step")
> melt1
    step variable  value
1  512.5   Temp.x 301.16
2  520.0   Temp.x     NA
...
```

Now, I want to for example do a histogram of the distribution of values. I do it like this:

```
p <- ggplot(data = melt1, aes(x = value, color = variable, fill = variable)) + geom_histogram(alpha = 0.4)
```

[image: I get this plot]

My problem is when I try to modify the Legend of this graph, I don't know how to! I've followed what is suggested in the R Graphics Cookbook book, but I've had no luck.

I've tried to do this, for example (to change the labels of the Legend):

```
> p + scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("d1", "d2"))
```

But I just create a "new" Legend box, like so

[image]

Or even removing the Legend completely

```
> p + scale_fill_discrete(guide = F)
```

I just get this

[image]

Finally, doing this also doesn't help

```
> p + scale_fill_discrete("")
```

Again, it just adds a new Legend box

[image]

Does anyone know what's happening here? It looks as if I'm actually modyfing another Label object, if that makes any sense. I've looked into other related questions in this site, but I haven't found someone having the same problem as me.

Comment: @Henrik I've rolled back your edits because the neatest way of solving the problem was actually to process the data in a more straightforward way (using `rbind`) rather than fiddling around with the labels on the legend. In general, I believe, the best way of using ggplot2 is to sort out the names of the variables, levels of factors, etc. in the input data rather than trying to change things in the data formatting. It makes for more readable plot code.

Answer (score 4):

Get rid of the `aes(color = variable...)` to remove the scale that belongs to `aes(color = ...)`.

```
ggplot(data = melt1, aes(x = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_histogram(alpha = 0.4) + 
  scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("d1", "d1")) # Change the labels for `fill` scale
```

[image]

This second plot contains `aes(color = variable...)`. Color in this case will draw colored outlines around the histogram bins. You can turn off the scale so that you only have one legend, the one created from `fill`

```
ggplot(data = melt1, aes(x = value, color = variable, fill = variable)) +
  geom_histogram(alpha = 0.4) +
  scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("d1", "d1")) +
  scale_color_discrete(guide = F) # Turn off the color (outline) scale
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward thing to do would be to not use `reshape2` or `merge` at all, but instead to `rbind` your data frames:

```
dfNew <- rbind(data.frame(d1, Group = "d1"),
  data.frame(d2, Group = "d2"))
ggplot(dfNew, aes(x = Temp, color = Group, fill = Group)) +
  geom_histogram(alpha = 0.4) +
  labs(fill = "", color = "")
```

If you wanted to vary alpha by group:

```
ggplot(dfNew, aes(x = Temp, color = Group, fill = Group, alpha = Group)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  labs(fill = "", color = "") +
  scale_alpha_manual("", values = c(d1 = 0.4, d2 = 0.8))
```

Note also that the default `position` for `geom_histogram` is `"stacked"`. There won't be overlap of the bars unless you use `geom_histogram(position = identity)`.

[image: Histogram]

Comment: So how do I changed now the Legend box? The ´scale_color_discrete´ and ´scale_fill_discrete("")´ functions have the same behaviour that I posted before.

Comment: @j_eiros why do you need to change them? I would general set up the data that is input to ggplot so it is correct to begin with. Or is it just to remove the legend title? I'll amend the code above to do that.

Comment: Thanks for that. One last question, do you know if it's possible to map the alpha value to a variable? Say I want one of the data series to be more opaque than the other, how could I do that?

Comment: @j_eiros alpha can be set in aes just like colour and fill. See edited answer.